# Spring Boot error controller retrieve original request

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

By default Spring Boot maps `/error` to `BasicErrorController`. I want to log the exception along with the request that causes the exception. How can I get the original request in `BasicErrorController` or a new `CustomErrorController`. It seems that Spring Boot will make a new request to `/error` when an exception is thrown and the orginal request info is gone or no way to map the error with the original request.
[image]

Comment: you may have a  look at this guide, https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc

Comment: @LaksithaRanasingha Thanks! I found that Spring Boot just forwards the request to /error but not create a new request. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Good article : https://www.baeldung.com/exception-handling-for-rest-with-spring

Comment: @Byeon0gam Thanks. The website is indeed a very good resource for learning Spring.

Answer (score 11):

Get it by:

```
String url = (String) request.getAttribute(RequestDispatcher.ERROR_REQUEST_URI);
```

Comment: Where is this docuemented?

Answer (score 5):

To avoid any misleading information, Spring Boot **DOES NOT** make a new request to `/error` endpoint. Instead, it wraps the exception in the original request and forwards it to `/error` endpoint. The request will be processed by `BasicErrorHandler` if you don't provide a custom error handler.

In this case, if you are using an `interceptor`, the interceptor will be invoked **twice** - one for the original request and the other for the forwarded request.

To retrieve the original request information, please look into the forwarded request's attributes. Basically, you can get the error message from these attributes `javax.servlet.error.message, javax.servlet.error.status_code, org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.EXCEPTION`.

And these are some resources that are related to error handling in Spring Boot:

- [spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc](http://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc)
- https://www.baeldung.com/exception-handling-for-rest-with-spring
- https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-custom-error-page

Comment: I got it using request.getAttribute(RequestDispatcher.FORWARD_SERVLET_PATH);

Answer (score 0):

If you are using controller advice to handle your exceptions then method with @ExceptionHandler can inject request as parameter, something like :

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class YourExceptionHandler
{
    @ExceptionHandler
    public ResponseEntity handleExceptions(HttpServletRequest request, Exception exception)
    {
        // use request to populate error object with details like requestId
        LOGGER.debug(String.valueOf(request));
        LOGGER.error(exception.getMessage(), exception);
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, at this time I would rather use the default `BasicErrorHandler` provided by Spring Boot. I already found the way to get the information of the original request. But your suggestion is still very useful. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example:

```
@RestController
public class MyErrorController implements ErrorController {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyErrorController.class);

    private static final String PATH = "/error";

    private final ErrorAttributes errorAttributes;

    public MyErrorController(ErrorAttributes errorAttributes) {
        this.errorAttributes = errorAttributes;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = PATH)
    public ErrorDTO error(WebRequest webRequest, HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {

        // Appropriate HTTP response code (e.g. 404 or 500) is automatically set by Spring.
        Map<String, Object> attrs = errorAttributes.getErrorAttributes(webRequest, ErrorAttributeOptions.defaults());

        LOG.warn("Forwarded Error Request: {} ", attrs.get("path"), (Throwable)
                httpServletRequest.getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.exception"));

        ErrorDTO dto = new ErrorDTO();
        dto.message = (String) attrs.get("error");
        dto.path = (String) attrs.get("path");
        dto.timestamp = attrs.get("timestamp").toString();
        return dto;
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleMethodArgumentNotValid(
        MethodArgumentNotValidException exception,
        HttpHeaders headers,
        HttpStatus status,
        WebRequest request) {
    OriginalRequestObject originalRequest = (OriginalRequestObject) exception.getBindingResult().getTarget();
    ErrorResponse errorResponse = new ErrorResponse(
            status.value(),
            originalRequest.getId() + " " + exception.getMessage());
    return ResponseEntity.status(status).body(myErrorResponse);
}
```